# jq: add new elements to list from other file

Tags: json, file, merge, jq

I have two json files.
File 1:

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": []
  }
}
```

File 2:

```
[
  { 
    "name": "first name",
    "path": [{
            "matcher": "exact",
    }]
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

I want to add all items from File 2 to the .data.items list in File 1.
How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're willing to normalize the detail file:

```
items=$(jq -c ' . | { data: { items: . }} ' 2.json)

jq -s '{ data: { items: map(.data.items[])}}' 1.json <(echo $items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both files contain valid JSON, you could do worse than:

```
jq --argfile extra 2.json '.data.items += $extra' 1.json
```